# Python: AttributeError: 'mpc' (or 'mpf') object has no attribute 'arcsin'

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, mpmath, mpc

I was trying to use Jacobi elliptical function from `mpmath`, but getting the error for the simple code given below:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as spi
from scipy import special as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sqrt, pow, log
from mpmath import ellipfun

sn = ellipfun('sn')
y=sn(0.5,-1)
print y

y1=y.real
print y1, np.arcsin(y), np.arcsin(y1)
```

I am getting the error even when I pass only the real part of the function `sn(0.5,-1)`.
I don't know whether I am making a mistake. Kindly help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I need other packages for rest of my program. So I import them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`y` is an `mpc` object, and `y.real` is an `mpf` object.  numpy knows nothing about such objects, so when you call `np.arcsin(y)`, the numpy code checks to see if the argument has an `arcsin()` method (that is, it looks for `y.arcsin()`).  If it does, it will call that function to compute the arcsin.  The `mpc` and `mpf` objects do not have such a method, which results in the error that you see.  (It would be nice if the error message said something like "numpy does not know how to compute the arcsin of an mpf object".)

Here's the same behavior demonstrated with a different object:

```
In [10]: class Foo:
    ...:     pass
    ...: 

In [11]: f = Foo()

In [12]: np.arcsin(f)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-aa4b1a80cd4e> in <module>()
----> 1 np.arcsin(f)

AttributeError: Foo instance has no attribute 'arcsin'
```

As pointed out in a comment by Hannebambel, you could use `mpmath.asin` instead of `np.arcsin`:

```
In [6]: import mpmath

In [7]: y = sn(0.5, -1)

In [8]: mpmath.asin(y)
Out[8]: mpc(real='0.52001273608158616', imag='0.0')
```

To use the numpy `arcsin` function, first convert to a plain floating point or complex by passing the `mpc` and `mpf` objects through the builtin functions `complex()` and `float()`, respectively:

```
In [19]: y
Out[19]: mpc(real='0.49689119041931196', imag='0.0')

In [20]: np.arcsin(float(y.real))
Out[20]: 0.52001273608158627

In [21]: np.arcsin(complex(y))
Out[21]: (0.52001273608158616+0j)
```

Or use `math.asin` instead of `numpy.arcsin`:

```
In [25]: import math

In [26]: math.asin(y.real)
Out[26]: 0.5200127360815863
```

Comment: I would rather use `mpmath.asin` as this allows to stay within this arbitrary precision library. Returns a mpmath.ctx_mp_python.mpf object, not a float like 'math.asin'.

Comment: @Hannebambel Yes, that makes sense.  I assumed Satadru has a reason for using `np.arcsin`, but maybe it was just lack of awareness of  `mpmath.asin`.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, I did not know about `mpmath.asin`. Actually I am very armature in python.